How to get all matches for regular expression when ending character of pattern matches more than once?
Here is my input string:
let input = "Hello, {un:23456} is under investigation {un:654, Bartek} along with Jason."

and simple extension:
extension String {
    func matchesFor(regularExpression: NSRegularExpression) -> [String] {
        let nsstring = self as NSString
        let matches = regularExpression.matches(in: self, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsstring.length))
        return matches.map { nsstring.substring(with: $0.range) }
    }
}

and the output is:
["{un:23456} is under investigation {un:654, Bartek}"]

instead of:
["{un:23456}", "{un:654, Bartek}"]

Why?
My regex is "\\{un:(:?[0-9]{1,9}).*\\}"

Make the .* ungreedy - .*?

You are an real engineer;) Thank you. One more thing. Is there a way to remove {} from output?. It would be best if I receive ["un:23456", "un:654, Bartek"]

you could try this to remove the {}: let results = output.map{String($0.dropFirst().dropLast())}

Put un:(:?[0-9]{1,9}).*? inside a group: (un:(:?[0-9]{1,9}).*?), and in the map nsstring.substring(with: $0.range(at: 1)). So add in the param of the method group: Int = 0, when it's 0, it's as currently coded, and call it with group: 1.

Why not a more specific pattern like \{un[^}]+\}" which looks for a opening brace followed by un followed by one or more characters which are not a closing brace followed by a closing brace. .* should be avoided unless you have no choice.

I would use a character class to terminate the match at the first }. [^}] means "match anything except }"
/\{([^}]*)\}/

https://regex101.com/r/t9eLmP/1

Change .* -> .*?. The ? stop * being greedy, match the string that ends with } and no more.
Or, get all between { }:
"\\{(.*?)\\}"

As you said in your comment, you also need to remove these curly braces:
let output = input.matchesFor(regularExpression: try .init(pattern: "\\{(.*?)\\}"))
    .map { $0.replacingOccurrences(of: "{", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "}", with: "") }

print(output)

//["un:23456", "un:654, Bartek"]


Updated as @Larme suggested:
func matchesFor(regularExpression: NSRegularExpression) -> [String] {
    let nsstring = self as NSString
    let matches = regularExpression.matches(in: self, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsstring.length))
    return matches.map { nsstring.substring(with: $0.range(at: 1)) } //<- here
}

let output = input.matchesFor(regularExpression: try .init(pattern: "\\{(.*?)\\}"))

print(output)

//["un:23456", "un:654, Bartek"]


Since you used a group (.*?), you can use that group instead of removing afterward the { and }. Also, you could do only one map instead of two, doing only one loop.

In your sample code: in the final map: nsstring.substring(with: $0.range(at: group)) adding parameter group: Int = 0 to the method and calling it with group = 1, then no need for your two map afterwards.

Thanks for pointing that out, that's a bad habit, I often make the functions like a chain. Edited.

Modern solution with Swift Regex.
extension String {
    func matchesFor(regex: Regex<(Substring, Substring)>) -> [String] {
        self.matches(of: regex).map{String($0.output.1)}
    }
}

let input = "Hello, {un:23456} is under investigation {un:654, Bartek} along with Jason."
let result = input.matchesFor(regex: /\{(un[^}]+)\}/)
print(result)

Regex<(Substring, Substring)> is required because to get rid of the enclosing braces the capture of a group is necessary.
The regex pattern \{(un[^}]+)\} searches for

\{ opening brace (escaped)
(  start of captured group
un characters "un"
[^}]+ one or more characters which are not "}"
) end of captured group
\} closing brace (escaped)

The desired output of each match is output.1 which is the same as  match(at: 1) of traditional NSRegularExpression.
